# add fonts in ckeditor library in django app

Tags: python-3.x, fonts, django-templates, ckeditor

In my Django project, I'm using the ck editor. Because I want to add text in a different-2 font, I want to add other fonts to CKEditor. how to add more typefaces to the ckeditor collection, such as Kurtidev, Mangal, and Devlish.

It ought to support fonts like Devlish, Kurtidev, and Mangal. so that I can add material in several fonts to my website.
I've included a fonts file to my project. I also included the file containing the typefaces in the template. I also modified the settings file for ckeditor. however my ckeditor does not show any changes.